# Is $\Gamma = Inv(Pol(\Gamma))$?

Tags: constraint-satisfaction

I'm reading [A Rendezvous of Logic, Complexity and Algebra](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0611018.pdf), my first introduction to the world of CSP. Let $\Gamma$ be a finite constraint language. It says in Pg. 9 that

> $Pol(\Gamma)$ is used to denote the set of all polymorphisms of $\Gamma$, that is,
>   $$Pol(Γ) = \{f : \forall R \in \Gamma, \textrm{ f is a polymorphism of }R\}.$$
>   Also, for a set of operations $O$, we use $Inv(O)$ to denote the set of relations having all operations in $O$ as a polymorphism, that is,
>   $$Inv(O) = \{R : \forall f \in O, \textrm{ f is a polymorphism of } R\}.$$

The answer to my question is: No (in fact it is a subset of $\Gamma$). But I don't understand why:

1. Isn't every $R\in \Gamma$ in $Inv(Pol(\Gamma))$?
2. Are the $R$'s from $Inv(O)$ allowed to come only from $\Gamma$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operation $\operatorname{Inv}(\operatorname{Pol}(\cdot))$ is a *closure* operation. This means that

1. $\Gamma \subseteq \operatorname{Inv}(\operatorname{Pol}(\Gamma))$.
2. $\operatorname{Inv}(\operatorname{Pol}(\Gamma)) = \operatorname{Inv}(\operatorname{Pol}(\operatorname{Inv}(\operatorname{Pol}(\Gamma))))$.

See for example [lecture notes of Jin-Yi Cai](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~jyc/880/Feb-16.pdf).